# SSH connection to gcloud VM instance not working

Tags: ssh, proxy, backend, gcloud, permission-denied

I am using a VM instance with 30gb disk space. Cloning my projects into this instance. While I was cloning one project, it showed "disk is out of space". So, I turned off all the processes running in this instance, closed all SSH connections and stopped the instance. Went to Disks, increased space from 30GB to 35GB. While starting a new SSH connection with this instance, it is not connecting. Sometimes, it goes on trying but doesnt connect. Sometimes, it shows an error
`Connection via Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy Failed`
`Code: 4003`
`Reason: failed to connect to backend`
`You may be able to connect without using the Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy.`
Tried to connect from gcloud shell, it shows me that no SSH keys are present. And `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` is empty. Tried to copy key from `google_compute_engine.pub` to `authorized_keys` but not worked. Tried by creating new key and then copying it to `authorized_keys` > Not worked. While copying these keys, it showed me `permission denied(publickey)` error. While connecting from gcloud shell too, shows the same erroe.

Comment: Enable the serial console in the Google Cloud Console for this compute engine instance. Boot the system and review the serial port output. Either the file system did not resize or there is a file system error. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-using-serial-console

Comment: In addition to John Hanley suggestion, if you get a 40003 error it might mean, according to the [troubleshooting SSH documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh#failed_to_connect_to_backend) that your VM doesn't have a public IP address and for which you haven't configured Identity-Aware Proxy on port 22.